# jdbc driver for microsoft sql enterprise manager 8.0

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using microsoft sql enterprise manager version 8.0 for the data storage .

Now i have prepared a jdbc program to fetch data from this database from a remote system and put it in my local system database . I have used sqljdbc4.jar driver to get the connection to the remote db. While running its showing an error saying version 8 sql is not supported by the provided jdbc driver.

Can you tell me what sql jdbc driver should i use for microsoft sql enterprise manager 8.0 .

Comment: try jtds driver http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver to connect Sql Server to Java application can be changed about version of Sql Server.

On the newest version of Sql Server you can use sqljdbc4.jar

On the MS Sql Enterprise Manager 8.0 (Sql Server 2000) you must use an older version of JDBC (version 3.0)

Go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=21599) to download the correct file.

Tell me if it's OK